# I have project for my school and I need help to continue

Tags: c

I need to create the same thing in this file : http://www.memoirepfe.fst-usmba.ac.ma/get/pdf/4078

It can be more than 3x3 chart

Here what i did to far

If you can help me done my project I will be thankful if not just help me with scan number in matrix it can be 5x5 6x7 so i need it good and thanks

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main() {

    int source,i,j,k,l,a[100][100],s[100],d[100];
    int destination;
    printf  ("Enter the number of source: \n");//used Google translate "Entrer le nombre de source :\n"
    scanf  ("%d",&source);
    printf  ("Entrer le nombre de destination :\n ");
    scanf  ("%d",&destination);

    printf  ("La saisie de couts de transports : \n");

    for(i=1;i<=source;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=destination;j++){
            printf("de source %d au destination %d \n",i,j );
            scanf("%d",& a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(i=1;i<=source;i++){
        for(j=1;j<=destination;j++){
            printf("%7d",a[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf  ("La saisie des disponibiltes existant aux sources : \n ");
    for(k=1;k<=source;k++){
        printf("la disponibilite de source %d \n",k);
        scanf("%d",& s[k]);  
    }

    printf("la saisie des demandes existant aux destinations: \n");
    for(l=1;l<=destination;l++){
        printf("la demande de la destination %d \n ",l);
        scanf("%d",& d[l]);  
    }

    




    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Step 1: Use 0 based indexing `for(i=1;i<=source;i++){` --> `for(i=0;i<source;i++){` as it is more C idiomatic.

Comment: Have you tried debugging using printf() ? A good first approach is to check every step by printing the result in the console and comparing with an example calculated by hand. You could also use breakpoints and a debugger to follow step by step what your program is doing.

Comment: @snus74 is right. pen, paper and printf statements can solve almost any problem.

Comment: I would love to help but I know no French, and i suspect many people dont.

Comment: Looks like the only thing you did is trying to read some input. I don't think you will get help here unless you actually try to solve the problem yourself first.

Comment: In addition to not linking content, but placing it directly into your post, and providing a  clear problem statement, consider using [Google translate](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=google+translate) to convert the text in your `printf` statements to English, as has been done for you in the first statement of your post.